# How should this statement be understood?

Tags: inequality

How many litres of water will have to be added to 1125 litres of the 45% solution
of acid so that the resulting mixture will contain more than 25% but less than 30% acid
content?

I am trying to solve this, but I am not getting this situation correctly.

$$(1125+x) \text{ of } 45\% > 1125 \text{ of } 25\%$$

$$(1125+x) \text{ of } 45\% < 1125 \text{ of } 30\%$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Assume that you add $x$ liters of the solution with acid. Then the final soultion will have $$1125+x$$ liters, of which $$1125\cdot0+x\cdot0.45=x\cdot0.45$$ will be acid. Thus in $1125+x$ liters you have $x\cdot0.45$ liters of acid which as percent is $$\frac{x\cdot0.45\cdot(100)}{1125+x}=\frac{45x}{1125+x}\%$$ of acid. Thus you need to solve for $x$ the inequality $$25\% \lt \frac{45x}{1125+x}\% \lt 30\%$$ or equivalently $$0.25 \lt \frac{0.45x}{1125+x} \lt 0.30$$

---

To solve you can start by inverting it $$\frac{1}{0.25} \gt \frac{1125+x}{0.45x} \gt \frac{1}{0.30} \iff 4 \gt \frac{1125}{0.45x}+\frac{1}{0.45}\gt \frac{10}{3} $$ Now $x$ is isolated and proceeding from here should be easier.